# Solutions of a equation on algebraic numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory

Take a complex number $(*)\ \alpha=a+bi$ with $a,b\in \mathbb R$ and suppose that $a^2+b^2=\frac{1}{n}$ with $n$ be a fixed positive integer.

The solutions of the equation $(*)$ are algebraic numbers?

Please any suggestion to solve this problem

Comment: All $a^2+b^2$ tells you about is the magnitude of $\alpha$. Its phase is undetermined so it may or may not be algebraic.

Comment: Counterexample: $b=ta$ for some transcendental number $t$ and $a=\frac1{\sqrt{n(1+t^2)}}$

Comment: For a more concrete counterexample, take $n=1$, $a=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}$ and $b=\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\pi}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, because the algebraic numbers by an easy argument are countable.   So for instance we could take $n=1$ and look at the unit circle.

In fact any circle is uncountable,  so this can't be true.